# AMAZON 500310: Invalid operation: syntax error at or near " Drop"

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I followed https://dwgeek.com/redshift-stored-procedure-return-result-set-working-example.html/ step of creating a stored procedure using a temporary table but facing the error above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample_return_table(tmp_table INOUT varchar(256)) 
AS '
  DECLARE
    row record;
  BEGIN
   EXECUTE ' DROP table if exists ' || tmp_table;
   EXECUTE ' CREATE temp TABLE  ' || tmp_table ||  ' AS SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables ';
  END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "DROP" 
Position: 132; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.
```

May I know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample Stored Procedure from [Overview of stored procedures in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp1(f1 int, f2 varchar)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'f1 = %, f2 = %', f1, f2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Notice that use of `$$` to identify the content of the procedure, whereas your code is using `'`.

The problem with using `'` is that it is also being used *inside* the procedure (eg just before `DROP`) and is therefore confusing Redshift.

Try changing to an unused sequence (such as `$$`) to avoid this problem.

Comment: $$ Cant be used in sql workbench. Thats why i have used ' ' as recommended by other people. ERROR: 42601: [Amazon](500310) unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$

Comment: When using SQL Workbench/J version 125, consider specifying an alternate delimiter as a workaround. Because the CREATE PROCEDURE contains SQL statements delimited with a semicolon (;), defining an alternate delimiter such as a forward slash (/) and placing it at the end of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement sends the entire statement to the Amazon Redshift server for processing. As shown in the following example.  What delimiter should i use in SQL workbench/j

Comment: The issue is not related to `$$`, but rather the semi-colon (`;`) that the SQL client thinks is the end of a command. You can continue to use `$$`, but that documentation page suggests setting the alternate delimiter to `/`, or possibly sending the whole command as a 'batch'. I'm not familiar with SQL Workbench, but see: [SQL Workbench: Creating stored procedures and triggers](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/understand-alternate-delim.html)

Comment: @Denise: you are right. "dollar quoting" support isn't enabled for Redshift (only for Postgres) - but I guess it makes sense to enable that for Redshift as well. I will change that

Comment: Sure. For this issue, I have decided to use SQL WORKBENCHJ version 124 which allows us to use $$.

Comment: it worked if I am using version 124. This problem occurs if you are using version 125. Somehow this issue is not fixed as I am asking for version 125. But I guess version 124 is fine for now.

Comment: Hi @Denise, great question!! $$ still can't be used with `version 125`. Please share if you have found a fix for this. Also that `single quotes` could not be used because `' '` is also used within the query

Comment: I ended up using version 124 and it works fine :)